# underscore.js with consolidate.js : how to change templateSettings?

Tags: node.js, express, underscore.js

I'm using Express.js on Node.js, and I marked parameter places with "**{{ }}**" brackets, but underscore use "**<% %>**" by default.

```
app.engine('html', cons.underscore);
// set .html as the default extension
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

When and how would I change templateSettings.interpolate to have "**{{ }}**" brackets in my templates before I call the render method?

Answer (score 2):

You change the template settings via the _.templateSetting object. Information is on the [underscore website](http://underscorejs.org/#template). Here's the code they use to change to Handlebars style brackets:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
template({name: "Mustache"});
=> "Hello Mustache!"
```

This can go anywhere in your code as it's modifying the global underscore object.

Comment: it's working on client's side but not in node.js modules environment!

Comment: Did you add this to your server as well?

Comment: Yes, before writing here i've tried, but nothing work, because app.render calls require('underscore') and then underscore is executed in sandbox, so our call _.templateSettings has no matter for underscore in sandbox.
Your code use the call underscore and rendering template by hands, but I want to use expresses native method - render!